any npm command not running even though node and npm installed
I'm not able to run any npm command not even "init" or "version" ones. It shows me following error:
% npm --version
evalmachine.<anonymous>:44
} = primordials;
    ^

ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
   [stack trace snip]
Node.js v21.7.3


node is installed but on checking the npm version it shows an error.
I uninstalled node and reinstalled but again the problem remains the same. The moment I go to install npm it starts showing this error.

what version of npm is installed? as npm --version doesn't work, go to /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/npm and check the content the package.json file there

Maybe you had an old version installed and upon reinstalling homebrew didn't replace npm with a recent version

@derpirscher , the first line of the file shows  "version" : "2.0.0".

Well, yeah, then you have npm 2.0 installed which is ancient (current version is 10.x). Don't know how that could happen, but thats the problem

@derpirscher Any way by which i can upgrade my npm version because it's not happening. Each time i reinstall my node ,same issue is there.

@derpirscher or suggest something by which i cam completely remove node/npm from my system.

I'm not very familiar with homebrew as I'm not a mac user, so I can't help you with this. But you could definitively check if after uninstalling node via homebrew that directory still exists and whether there is some cleanup or similar option in homebrew ... Not sure what happens (and therefore I wouldn't recommend it) if you just delete that orphaned node_modules directory after uninstalling node ...

thanks mate !!! I don't know what happened but when i ran the same commands through my vs code terminal it worked. After  i ran npx create command.(ps. npm command was not working here also ) But then everything started working fine. Might has been a glitch/bug only on my machine.
